# ThreadPool implementation in C is at same performance or slower when compared to non parallelized code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I've been working on implementing a ThreadPool in C to optimize the processing of my program, which involves various tasks related to neural network linear algebra. However, I'm encountering performance issues when using the ThreadPool. Surprisingly, the ThreadPool is not providing the expected speedup and, in some cases, is even slower than sequential processing.

To investigate this, I conducted a comparison with CUDA, and the CUDA implementation shows a significant speedup. However, I'm struggling to identify the factors causing the ThreadPool to underperform.

Here are some specifics about my setup:

- I'm using a ThreadPool with 4 threads, even though my CPU supports 12 threads.(More threads doesn't translate to more performance)
- I am running a model to train the MNIST model in 1 batch to test the performance.(60,000 rows)

I'm new to multithreading and seeking guidance on how to diagnose and address the performance bottlenecks in my ThreadPool implementation.

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on profiling and optimizing my ThreadPool would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
struct ThreadPool* create_thread_pool(int num_threads) {
    struct ThreadPool* thread_pool = (struct ThreadPool*) malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadPool));
    thread_pool->is_active = 1;
    thread_pool->num_threads = num_threads;
    thread_pool->threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    thread_pool->num_pending_tasks = 0;
    thread_pool->num_threads_exited = 0;

    thread_pool->task_queue = init_task_queue(200);

    thread_pool->lock = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    thread_pool->capacity_lock = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    thread_pool->capacity_signal = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    thread_pool->task_available_cond = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    thread_pool->all_tasks_done = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    thread_pool->pop_task = pop_task;
    thread_pool->push_task = push_task;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread_pool->threads[i], NULL, run_thread, thread_pool);
    }
    
    return thread_pool;
}

void* run_thread(void* args) {
    struct ThreadPool* thread_pool = (struct ThreadPool*) args;
    struct Task* task = NULL;

    while(thread_pool->is_active == 1) {    
        // Lock to coordinate thread states: waiting for a task or dequeuing a task from the queue
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_pool->lock);
        while(thread_pool->task_queue->element_count == 0 && thread_pool->is_active == 1){
            pthread_cond_wait(&thread_pool->task_available_cond, &thread_pool->lock);
            // log_info("thread: %lu is waiting for tasks", pthread_self());
        }
        if(thread_pool->is_active == 0) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->lock);
            break;
        }
        task = thread_pool->pop_task(thread_pool);
        thread_pool->task_queue->element_count--;
        // log_info("thread: %lu is got a task", pthread_self());

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->lock);

        task->function(task->data);

        // lock that checks if we are done with the work to signal all_tasks_done cond.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);

        thread_pool->num_pending_tasks --;
        if(thread_pool->num_pending_tasks <= 0) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&thread_pool->all_tasks_done);
            // log_info("thread: %lu signalled all tasks are done!", pthread_self());
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void wait_for_all_tasks(struct ThreadPool* thread_pool) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);
    while(thread_pool->num_pending_tasks > 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&thread_pool->all_tasks_done, &thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);
    }

    // log_info("thread_pool is done with tasks! returning.");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);
}

struct TaskQueue* init_task_queue(int capacity) {
    struct TaskQueue* task_queue = (struct TaskQueue*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct TaskQueue));
    
    task_queue->tasks = (struct Task**) malloc(capacity * sizeof(struct Task*));
    task_queue->capacity = capacity;
    task_queue->element_count = 0;

    return task_queue;
}

void push_task(struct ThreadPool* thread_pool, struct Task* task) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_pool->lock);
    while(thread_pool->task_queue->element_count >= thread_pool->task_queue->capacity) {
        printf("At full capacity, waiting for others tasks to finish...");
        pthread_cond_wait(&thread_pool->capacity_signal, &thread_pool->lock);
    }

    thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[thread_pool->task_queue->element_count] = task;
    thread_pool->task_queue->element_count ++;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);

    thread_pool->num_pending_tasks++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&thread_pool->task_available_cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_pool->lock);
}


struct Task* pop_task(struct ThreadPool* thread_pool) {
    struct Task* task = thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < thread_pool->task_queue->element_count - 1; i++) {
        thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[i] = thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[i + 1];
    }
    thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[thread_pool->task_queue->element_count - 1] = NULL;
    
    pthread_cond_signal(&thread_pool->capacity_signal);  // signal that a task has been popped from the queue

    return task;
}


void destroy_thread_pool(struct ThreadPool* thread_pool) {
    thread_pool->is_active = 0;

    // wake up each thread from their sleep caused by lack of tasks and trigger exit from the while loop
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&thread_pool->task_available_cond);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_pool->num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread_pool->threads[i], NULL);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_pool->task_queue->element_count; i++) {
        free(thread_pool->task_queue->tasks[i]);
    }

    free(thread_pool->threads);

    free(thread_pool->task_queue->tasks);
    free(thread_pool->task_queue);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&thread_pool->lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&thread_pool->capacity_lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&thread_pool->pending_tasks_lock);

    pthread_cond_destroy(&thread_pool->capacity_signal);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&thread_pool->all_tasks_done);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&thread_pool->task_available_cond);

    free(thread_pool);
}


struct Task* create_task(void(*function)(void*), void* data) {
    struct Task* task = (struct Task*) malloc(sizeof(struct Task));

    task->function = function;
    task->data = data;

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Look up how to use the profiling / instrumentation tools available for your specific operating system and/or compiler. Code instrumentation essentially allows you to see what functions, or even lines of code, are spending the most time being executed. Other system utilities may also be beneficial, such as examining how much thread context switching, blocking I/O, or kernel access your program is doing. In general, you need a fair bit of processing per task before it makes sense to split that into a thread pool. Your question does not show this, nor indicate how much processing each task does.

Comment: "ThreadPool is not providing the expected speedup" Why would it? That's not what a thread pool does. A thread pool provides a way to re-use a small number of long-lived threads to perform a large number of short-lived tasks. Whether or not there is any speed up will depend almost entirely on how you write the task functions that you submit to the thread pool—on how tasks running in different pool threads interact with each other.

Comment: The speed-up available from parallelization is controlled by [Amdah's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) — or by variations on that.  You have to factor in the cost of setting up the threads and managing the thread pool, and so on.  If the overheads are high, the benefit from parallelization may be small or non-existent.